# What's the name of this spider?

Tags: species-identification

Recently, I was taking a walk down by a riverbank and saw this spider:
[image: Spider On Riverbank]
**Here's all the info I think would be useful**

- Where? Missoula Montana, United States of America. Specifically, Greenough Park, on the riverbank (as mentioned earlier)
- When? today, May 28, 2019
- Behavior? They were hard to approach and scuttled away fairly speedily whenever I approached.
- Population? They were *everywhere*, everywhere I looked they seemed to be there, occasionally, I found them in pairs, but never in groups of three.
- Additional Info: they were passive until approached, moving rarely if observed from a distance, but when they did move it seemed that their movements were somewhat sporadic, with quick bursts of speed and then stopping and resuming (if they found that necessary)